# libc:amd64 is half-installed and preventing other things from upgrading or being installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am having some issues after an interrupted upgrade. After doing `sudo apt update`, I ran `sudo apt upgrade` and I got:

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
```

So, I ran

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

and the output was:

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
```

If I try to run `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6` I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')`
```

Trying `sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin` gets me:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.33)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I have the "newest version" but it needs a version newer than that?

Comment: That gets me `Command line option --reinstall is not understood in combination with the other options`

Comment: It seems the person I am talking to keeps deleting their comments or else I cannot see them for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar problem and got past it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.32-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```